# Index Match Match query Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

Good day.

I am having some difficulties inserting an Index Match Match formula into Excel 2013, and I can't for the life of me work out where I have gone wrong.

I have a data table (as seen in the screenshot). On the left hand column I have a list of sites; across the top I have a list of weeks, with the table filled with sale predictions. I basically want to bring through the sales predictions For a specific named site and week in rows 22 and 23, and the formula I have is:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(B2:AO20,MATCH(B22,B3:B20,0),
MATCH(B23,C2:AO2,0))),0,INDEX(B2:AO20,MATCH(B22,B3:B20,0),MATCH(B23,C2:AO2,0)))
```

All the is being is returned is a 0 value; without the error handling, all it returns is a #N/A!.

Is anyone able to advise me or point me in the right direction at all please?

Screenshot is hopefully below

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq5fq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps protect this with an ISERROR statement, but otherwise this should work:

```
=vlookup(b22,$b$2:$ao$20,match(b23,$b$2:$ao$2),false)
```

Although instead of protection (or as well as) I'd make the site and week cells into validated lists

Comment: Thank you for the response, this works absolutely perfectly.